# Does Rakudo Perl 6 have the struct like case Class in Scala?

Tags: pattern-matching, raku

In Scala, case Class looks like this:

```
val alice   = Person("Alice",   25, Address("1 Scala Lane", "Chicago", "USA"))
val bob     = Person("Bob",     29, Address("2 Java Ave.",  "Miami",   "USA"))
val charlie = Person("Charlie", 32, Address("3 Python Ct.", "Boston",  "USA"))

for (person <- Seq(alice, bob, charlie)) {
    person match {
        case Person("Alice", 25, Address(_, "Chicago", _) => println("Hi Alice!")
        case Person("Bob",   29, Address("2 Java Ave.", "Miami", "USA")) => println("Hi Bob!")
        case Person(name,   age, _) => println(s"Who are you, $age year-old person named $name?")
    }
```

I wanted to implement this in Perl 6, but failed:

```
class Address {
    has Str $.street;
    has Str $.city;
    has Str $.country;
}

class Person {
    has Str $.name;
    has Int $.age;
    has $.address;
}

my $alice   = Person.new(:name("Alice"),   :age(25), :address(Address.new(:street("1 Scala Lane"), :city("Chicago"), :country("USA"))));
my $bob     = Person.new(:name("Bob"),     :age(29), :address(Address.new(:street("2 Java Ave."), :city("Miami"), :country("USA"))));
my $charlie = Person.new(:name("Charlie"), :age(32), :address(Address.new(:street("3 Python Ct."), :city("Boston"), :country("USA"))));

for ($alice, $bob, $charlie) -> $s {
  given $s {
    # when Person { say $alice }; # works!
    when Person.new(:name("Alice"),   :age(25), :address(Address.new(:street("1 Scala Lane"), :city("Chicago"), :country("USA")))) {
      say "Hi Alice!"; # doesn't work
    }
    when Person.new(:name("Bob"),     :age(29), :address(Address.new(:street("2 Java Ave."), :city("Miami"), :country("USA")))) {
       say "Hi Bob!" # doesn't work
    }
    when Person.new(:name("Charlie"), :age(32), :address(Address.new(:street("3 Python Ct."), :city("Boston"), :country("USA")))) {
      say "Who are you, $age year-old person named $name?"; # doesn't work
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like that pattern match in Scala in more powerfull. But I wonder if Rakudo Perl 6 can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`* eqv`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/eqv) in your `when` statements to check if the structures of two objects are identical.

```
class Address {
    has Str $.street;
    has Str $.city;
    has Str $.country;
}

class Person {
    has Str $.name;
    has Int $.age;
    has $.address;
}

my $alice   = Person.new(:name("Alice"), :age(25), :address(Address.new(:street("1 Scala Lane"), :city("Chicago"), :country("USA"))));
my $bob     = Person.new(:name("Bob"), :age(29), :address(Address.new(:street("2 Java Ave."), :city("Miami"), :country("USA"))));
my $charlie = Person.new(:name("Charlie"), :age(32), :address(Address.new(:street("3 Python Ct."), :city("Boston"), :country("USA"))));

for ($alice, $bob, $charlie) {
    when * eqv Person.new(:name("Alice"),:age(25), :address(Address.new(:street("1 Scala Lane"), :city("Chicago"), :country("USA")))) {
        say "Hi Alice!";
    }

    when * eqv Person.new(:name("Bob"), :age(29), :address(Address.new(:street("2 Java Ave."), :city("Miami"), :country("USA")))) {
       say "Hi Bob!";
    }
    when Person {
       say "Who are you, {.age} year-old person named {.name}?";
    }
}
```

---

Additional notes:

In this code, the `for` loop without a signature is automatically setting the topic (i.e. `$_`), so a `given` block isn't needed.

The `{.age}` inside the last `when` block is accessing the `.age` method of `$_` and interpolating it into the string.

Also, since objects smart match to themselves, you get the exact same results using the following `for` loop:

```
for ($alice, $bob, $charlie) {
    when $alice { say "Hi Alice!"                                          }
    when $bob   { say "Hi Bob!"                                            }
    when Person { say "Who are you, {.age} year-old person named {.name}?" }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! one more question, why not use `$_ eqv` instead of  `* eqv`? As far as I konw, the asterisk in `term` context is `WhateverCode`, right?

Comment: You are correct. `$_ eqv` works as well. As I understand it, `* eqv Person.new(...)`  creates a block like `{$_ eqv Person.new(...)}` (which would also work if you explicitly typed it up). Personally, `* eqv` just seems more natural to me.

Comment: To take it a step further, `if` (and `$_`) makes more sense than `when` in this case, since you're fully specifying all the variables. The `when` statement isn't acting like a lambda, except because you used `*` instead of `$_`.